# NoSuchMethodError:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.begin

Tags: java, orientdb

I am getting below error while upgrading orient db core to 3.1.4:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.begin(Lcom/orientechnologies/orient/core/tx/OTransaction$TXTYPE;)Lcom/orientechnologies/orient/core/db/document/ODatabaseDocumentTx;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.begin(Lcom/orientechnologies/orient/core/tx/OTransaction$TXTYPE;)Lcom/orientechnologies/orient/core/db/document/ODatabaseDocumentTx;
```

Is it because, ODatabaseDocumentTx.begin() is depricated in 3.1.4.

Comment: what is the alternative API for this

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to move to the new 3.x multimode API

http://orientdb.com/docs/3.1.x/java/Java-MultiModel-API.html

The 3.x JAVA API is cleaner than the 2.1.x one

Comment: This is a major change, is there any alternative